# html lists with specific characters?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Is there a way to style a unordered list using the greater than symbol or any symbol I choose?

```
\> one  
\> two  
\> three


♦ one  
♦ two  
♦ three
```

without the use of url()?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use li:before

```
<style>
ul {    list-style: none;   }
li:before { content: '> '}
</style>
<ul>
<li>xyz</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

I up-modded the existing answer, which is how you do it entirely BTB.  To get it working in IE 6-7, you need to rasterize your desired item marker and do something like the following instead:

```
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: $length;
  background-image: url($image);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

...where `$length` is the aggregate width of your bitmapped list item marker and the desired negative space between the list item and the background image.  In its turn, `$image` is the valid URI of the rasterized marker. A `background-position` value might also be desirable.

There is also `list-style-image` (which does the work of all the properties used above), but it carries one very big caveat: the negative space you want around the image needs to be supplied **in the image**, a requirement which carries its share of pitfalls.

Finally there's no reason why you can't use the `background` shorthand property, but I avoid that - and its companion `font` - because values assigned to those shorthand properties are sometimes parsed in unexpected ways unless all values are present.